# Cloned inputs are not selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form where the user can add some more fields by clicking a button. It's made by cloning, changing the names, and apending the fields on the div:

```
$("#add").click(function(){
    var linha = $("#linha").clone();

    var num = $("#cont").val();
    var novo = parseInt(num) + 1;
    novo = novo.toString();

    linha.find('#FaturamentoHoraExtra'+num+'Nome').attr({'name': 'data[FaturamentoHoraExtra]['+novo+'][nome]'});
    linha.find('#FaturamentoHoraExtra'+num+'Nome').val('');
    linha.find('#FaturamentoHoraExtra'+num+'Responsabilidade').attr({'name': 'data[FaturamentoHoraExtra]['+novo+'][responsabilidade]'});
    linha.find('#FaturamentoHoraExtra'+num+'Responsabilidade').removeAttr("selected");
    linha.find('#FaturamentoHoraExtra'+num+'MaodeobraId').attr({'name': 'data[FaturamentoHoraExtra]['+novo+'][responsabilidade]'});
    linha.find('#FaturamentoHoraExtra'+num+'MaodeobraId').removeAttr("selected");
    linha.find('#FaturamentoHoraExtra'+num+'Salario').attr({'name': 'data[FaturamentoHoraExtra]['+novo+'][salario]'});
    linha.find('#FaturamentoHoraExtra'+num+'Salario').val('');
    linha.find('#FaturamentoHoraExtra'+num+'Qtd50').attr({'name': 'data[FaturamentoHoraExtra]['+novo+'][qtd_50]'});
    linha.find('#FaturamentoHoraExtra'+num+'Qtd50').val('');
    linha.find('#FaturamentoHoraExtra'+num+'Valor50').attr({'name': 'data[FaturamentoHoraExtra]['+novo+'][valor_50]'});
    linha.find('#FaturamentoHoraExtra'+num+'Valor50').val('');
    linha.find('#FaturamentoHoraExtra'+num+'Qtd100').attr({'name': 'data[FaturamentoHoraExtra]['+novo+'][qtd_100]'});
    linha.find('#FaturamentoHoraExtra'+num+'Qtd100').val('');
    linha.find('#FaturamentoHoraExtra'+num+'Valor100').attr({'name': 'data[FaturamentoHoraExtra]['+novo+'][valor_100]'});
    linha.find('#FaturamentoHoraExtra'+num+'Valor100').val('');
    linha.find('#FaturamentoHoraExtra'+num+'Dsr').attr({'name': 'data[FaturamentoHoraExtra]['+novo+'][dsr]'});
    linha.find('#FaturamentoHoraExtra'+num+'Dsr').val('');
    linha.find('#FaturamentoHoraExtra'+num+'Total').attr({'name': 'data[FaturamentoHoraExtra]['+novo+'][total]'});
    linha.find('#FaturamentoHoraExtra'+num+'Total').val('');
    linha.find('#FaturamentoHoraExtra'+num+'Obs').attr({'name': 'data[FaturamentoHoraExtra]['+novo+'][obs]'});
    linha.find('#FaturamentoHoraExtra'+num+'Obs').val('');

    linha.appendTo("#bloco");

    $("#cont").val(novo);

    return false;
});
```

All the fields are automatically calculated by some functions. This is how I made this:

```
$("input[name$='[dsr]']").change(function(){
    somaColaborador();
    totalDsr();
    totalGeral();
});
$("input[name$='[valor_50]']").change(function(){
    total50();
    somaColaborador();
    totalDsr();
    totalGeral();
});
$("input[name$='[valor_100]']").change(function(){
    total100();
    somaColaborador();
    totalDsr();
    totalGeral();
});
$("input[name$='[porcentagem]']").change(function(){
    porcentagemRateio();
});
```

I works, but the new fields cloned by the "original" are not selected, although they have the same end name. So, the calculation is not made and I'm not understanding why.

Comment: Just looks like you are overcomplicating it and anyway rendering invalid HTML markup with duplicate IDs. If you provide MCVE or at least relevant HTML markup, i guess someone could post a better/more readable and maintainable way

Comment: Still be aware, this results in invalid HTML markup, getting duplicate IDs: `var linha = $("#linha").clone();` **&&** `linha.appendTo("#bloco");`. Then you get at least two elements with same id `linha` in the DOM, which is invalid. BTW, the same things apply for all its descendants. Better would be to not use IDs here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, it sounds like your cloned elements aren't functioning as expected after creation.

When dynamically creating elements and expecting the event handlers to work for them, you'll need to use the [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function in jQuery as opposed to `click()` which will target elements that exist presently and those that are created in the future :

```
$(document).on('change','input[name$="[dsr]"]',function(){
    somaColaborador();
    totalDsr();
    totalGeral();
});
$(document).on('change','input[name$="[valor_50]"]',function(){
    total50();
    somaColaborador();
    totalDsr();
    totalGeral();
});
$(document).on('change','input[name$="[valor_100]"]',function(){
    total100();
    somaColaborador();
    totalDsr();
    totalGeral();
});
$(document).on('change','input[name$="[porcentagem]"]',function(){
    porcentagemRateio();
});
```

The `click()` function would only wire up these event handlers to work for elements that existed in the DOM when the event-handler was created.

Comment: I was in the process of updating the syntax shortly after posting it, realizing the same thing. It has since been changed.

Comment: Instead of delegating event, you could just pass `true` to `clone()` method to copy any bound event or data, including any of them bound to any descendant ones.

Answer (score 1):

Use event delegation to account for elements that will be created later:

```
$(document).on("change", "input[name$='[dsr]']", function(){
  ...
});

etc
```